# javaScript Beginner: Sending data from java-script to servlet?

Tags: javascript

I am creating dynamic form in JavaScript. I want to send the data's from JavaScript to servlet. I dont use any submit Button in my Form.Using button only i want to send the data's. Anyone help me please.

This is my code:

```
var myform=document.createElement("form");
myform.setAttribute("id", "myform");

var tname=document.createElement('input');
tname.setAttribute('type','text');
tname.setAttribute('name', "name");

var leaveMessage=document.createElement('input');
leaveMessage.setAttribute('type','button');
leaveMessage.setAttribute('name', "msgButton");
leaveMessage.setAttribute('value', "Leave Message");

myform.appendChild(tname);
myform.appendChild(leaveMessage);

document.body.appendChild(myform);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add some statements also

```
var myform=document.createElement("form");
myform.setAttribute("id", "myform");
myform.setAttribute('action', "/mypage");
myform.setAttribute('method', "post");

var tname=document.createElement('input');
tname.setAttribute('type','text');
tname.setAttribute('name', "name");
var leaveMessage=document.createElement('input');
leaveMessage.setAttribute('type','button');
leaveMessage.setAttribute('name', "msgButton");
leaveMessage.setAttribute('value', "Leave Message");

myform.appendChild(tname);
myform.appendChild(leaveMessage);

document.body.appendChild(myform);

document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Comment: Using the attribute 'action', "/mypage" <- this would be your servlet name.

Comment: set action of form : myform.setAttribute('action', "/mypage");

Comment: But it show an error. It could not find the server correctly. I have my servlet program in com.offline package. And servlet name is LeaveMessage.java. I gave in a action attribute like this. Am i right?

Comment: myform.setAttribute('action',"/com.livechat.offline.leavemessage/LeaveMessage");